# Why do I only get 1-dimensional arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
    var $arr = {
      field_hide : '',
      field_values: '',
      field_triggers: {}
    }

    function setTrigger ($trigger, $values, $show, $arr)  {
      $arr.field_hide += $show + ',';
      $arr.field_values += $values + ',';
      $arr.field_triggers[$trigger] = [];   
      $arr.field_triggers[$trigger].push([$values, $show]);
      return $arr;
    }

    $arr = setTrigger('file_drive','local','local_key,local_duk',$arr);
    $arr = setTrigger('file_drive','cloud','cloud_key,cloud_duk',$arr);
    console.log($arr)
```

Why do I get only one-dimensional arrays? Who can help me with this problem?
The result I want is as follows:

```js
{
 "field_hide": "local_key,local_duk,cloud_key,cloud_duk,",
 "field_values": "local,cloud,",
 "field_triggers": {
  "file_drive": [
    ["local","local_key,local_duk"],
    ["cloud","cloud_key,cloud_duk"]
   ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty well-written, but you need to edit your title to some more specific (and searchable). I would use something like "Why do I only get 1-dimensional arrays?". Also your first snippet is good (love it when people put code in a proper snippet) but the second one should be a simple code block instead (since it's not intended to be runnable code). Just some friendly tips since you're new :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the array to an empty array every time with this line:

```
$arr.field_triggers[$trigger] = [];
```

Instead you need to check if the array has already been defined, like so:

```js
var $arr = {
    field_hide: '',
    field_values: '',
    field_triggers: {}
}

function setTrigger($trigger, $values, $show, $arr) {
    $arr.field_hide += $show + ',';
    $arr.field_values += $values + ',';

    if (!$arr.field_triggers[$trigger]) {
        $arr.field_triggers[$trigger] = [];
    }

    $arr.field_triggers[$trigger].push([$values, $show]);
    return $arr;
}

$arr = setTrigger('file_drive', 'local', 'local_key,local_duk', $arr);
$arr = setTrigger('file_drive', 'cloud', 'cloud_key,cloud_duk', $arr);
console.log($arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice and answer!  ^_^

Comment: @mxh861001 No worries :D

Answer (score 0):

It's because you reset `file_drive` to an empty array every time before adding the new content with this line `$arr.field_triggers[$trigger] = [];`. You can add an `if` statement to determine whether or not to create a new array.

```js
    var $arr = {
      field_hide : '',
      field_values: '',
      field_triggers: {}
    }

    function setTrigger ($trigger, $values, $show, $arr)  {
      $arr.field_hide += $show + ',';
      $arr.field_values += $values + ',';

      if (!$arr.field_triggers[$trigger]) {
        $arr.field_triggers[$trigger] = [];
      }

      $arr.field_triggers[$trigger].push([$values, $show]);
      return $arr;
    }

    $arr = setTrigger('file_drive','local','local_key,local_duk',$arr);
    $arr = setTrigger('file_drive','cloud','cloud_key,cloud_duk',$arr);
    console.log($arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! ^_^

Comment: No problem. I think @Clonkex beat me to the submit button :D

Answer (score -1):

you are initializing  `$arr.field_triggers[$trigger] = [];`   with empty arry every time , use this code below

```js
var $arr = {
      field_hide : '',
      field_values: '',
      field_triggers: {$trigger:[]}
    };

    function setTrigger ($trigger, $values, $show, $arr)  {
      $arr.field_hide += $show + ',';
      $arr.field_values += $values + ',';
      $arr.field_triggers.$trigger.push([$values, $show]);
      return $arr;
    }

    $arr = setTrigger('file_drive','local','local_key,local_duk',$arr);
    $arr = setTrigger('file_drive','cloud','cloud_key,cloud_duk',$arr);
    console.log($arr)
```

Comment: The premise is correct, but the solution offered is not correct. `$arr.field_triggers.$trigger.push([$values, $show]);` doesn't work how you think; it makes a property called "$trigger" instead of using the contents of the `$trigger` variable.

Comment: I had defined this array when initializing $arr object field_triggers: {$trigger:[]}

Comment: Yep but that's not correct either. The OP doesn't want an array called "$trigger", he wants an array called the contents of the `$trigger` variable (which is a parameter of the `setTrigger` function), which in his example is `file_drive`. Compare the results of running your answer's snippet to the results of my answer's snippet and you'll see what I mean.